# Search for words against Excel and PDF file

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel, pdf

I am looking for an application or service which will allow me to check a list of words (client names) against an Excel or PDF file. Is there a way to do this?

My preferred OS is Mac, but have access to Windows in case.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel, copy and paste the client names into the Excel book and use vlookup to compare.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx